# Layout Editor in Android Studio is moving constantly widgets

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I wanted to start using new ConstraintLayout in this version:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

The problem is that layout is constantly moving. I will try to explain this.

First I move widget on layout, and I see this:

[image: first]

But after few seconds, grey rectangle which represents button moves to the left top.

[image: second]

So do other components. It's frustraiting especially when I have more widgets. Constraints are set correctly but views which represents widgets are always on the top left. If I click on widget, they return to position which is pointed by constraints but again just for few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart studio after updating to alpha 9 -- if this doesn't work, do File->Invalidate Caches. This should fix the problem.